# Find the product of $5x^2+5xy-9y^2$ and $5x^2-5xy-9y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the product of $5x^2+5xy-9y^2$ and $5x^2-5xy-9y^2$

I did a straight-up multiplication of every term and got the correct answer, $25x^4-115x^2y^2+81y^4$

However given the identical expressions given (differing only in sign), I can't help but feel there is a pattern/simplification I'm not seeing here and a direct multiplication is in fact the wrong (or inefficient) method. I thought it could be of the form $(a+b)(a-b)$, but the signs don't match. Thank you.

Comment: $a=5x^2-9y^2,b=5xy$

Comment: perhaps this would be easier: Find the product of $5x^2-9y^2+5xy$ and $5x^2-9y^2-5xy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let :
$$a = 5x^2 -9y^2  \\ b = 5xy $$
This implies that
$$5x^2 + 5xy -9y^2 = a + b $$
$$5x^2 - 5xy - 9y^2 = a - b $$

and therfore :
$$(5x^2 + 5xy -9y^2)(5x^2 - 5xy - 9y^2)=(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2 = (5x^2 -9y^2)^2 - (5xy)^2= 25x^4 + 81y^4-115x^2y^2$$